# Mysql and C integration

Tags: mysql, c, database

I am having trouble on connecting my C program to mysql. I've done most of the research but seems its quite difficult. Can someone please help? the image below shows the error using the command I typed to compile the code.

[image]

Your answers are highly appreciated.
BTW, I am a windows user.

Comment: You need mysql client development headers and libraries to link against http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ (on centos is `yum install mysql-devel`). Can't help you on windows.

Comment: I guessed your OS just by looking at the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set.  I believe you need that to be able to find the libraries required by the linker.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a quirk of Windows, but I suspect the problem is the extra `/` in

```
   -L/C:\xampp....
```

try using `-LC:\xampp\mysql\lib` instead.

Edit: Sadly, it looks like [you will need to compile with Visual Studio rather than gcc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html).

Comment: thanks timothy, it works but I have still errors upon compilation..see below thanks.

Comment: running this code: 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

void main(){
 MYSQL *conn;
   MYSQL_RES *res;
   MYSQL_ROW row;
   char *server = "localhost";
   char *user = "root";
   char *password = "";
   char *database = "aldee_info";
   conn = mysql_init(NULL);
   /* Connect to database */
   if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   /* send SQL query */

Comment: if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   res = mysql_use_result(conn);
   /* output table name */
   printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      printf("%s \n", row[0]);
   /* close connection */
   mysql_free_result(res);
   mysql_close(conn);
}
 I fall with this error and they're plenty.
Warning: .drective '/DEFAULTLIB: "LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized